# How to use JavaScript to conditionally format a grouped view of a SP13 list

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering, view-formatting

I have found examples that allow for highlighting a row based on date, I need to also highlight the 2 group tabs above that row
example
Group(highlight red if any row in group meets condition)
SubGroup(highlight red if any row in group meets condition)
Row (highlight red if list item meets condition)

the code I have now is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function (ctx) {
            // get today's date
            var today = new Date();
            // zero out the time portion so we will only compare days
            today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                // get the date set in your date YourDateField
                var itemDate = new Date(rows[i]['ContractExpirationDate']);
                // zero out the time portion so we only compare days
                itemDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
                if (row!=null&&itemDate <= today) {                  
                    row.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';                  
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to examine the HTML that SharePoint is generating for the group and subgroup "tabs" (as you say), the things you want to add highlighting to, and look for their relationship with the `row` you are highlighting in that code snippet, and look for patterns you can use to find those elements when starting at the `row` element. Do those group and subgroup tabs have particular classes you can reliably use to find them? Are they particular kinds of HTML elements? Are they parent elements of the `row` so you can go directly up the DOM tree to find them, or will you have to go up to a certain point and then find a sibling element? (And then maybe even traverse back *down* into the sibling to find those elements?)

Once you understand the relationship between the row you find in your code snippet and the additional HTML elements you want to highlight, add into your code the code required to traverse the HTML and find those other elements starting from the `row` element you already have, and then once you get those other elements, add the highlighting styling you want.

Even without jQuery, vanilla JavaScript has functions you can use to find other elements either up the DOM tree (like [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)) or down the DOM tree (like [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)) that start from a given [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).